# 2D Array Bitmap reader lacks support for duplicate colors in the same row in p5.js

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array, bitmap, p5.js

Using p5.js, I have constructed a function that reads a two-dimensional array and draws it onto the canvas using the color that corresponds with the string to the `colors` object in each position. This is my code:

```js
let colors = {
  r: "red",
  g: "green",
  b: "blue",
  y: "yellow",
  o: "orange",
  bl: "black",
  w: "white",
  t: "transparent",
  i: "indigo",
  v: "violet",
  c: "cyan",
};

let myMap = [
  ["r", "o", "y", "g"],
  ["b", "i", "o", "v"],
  ["o", "y", "g", "b"],
  ["i", "v", "r", "o"],
];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  rectMode(CENTER)
  readMap(myMap, 50, 50, 150, 150);
}

function readMap(bitmap, x = 0, y = 0, w = null, h = null) {
  for (let block of bitmap) {
    for (let block2 of block) {
      fill(colors[block2]);
      noStroke();
      push();
      translate(x, y);
      // If a width and height are specified, render it as a rectangle with that size.
      if (w && h) scale(w/width, h/height);
      rect(
        block.indexOf(block2) * (width / block.length),
        bitmap.indexOf(block) * (height / bitmap.length),
        width / block.length,
        height / bitmap.length
      );
      pop();
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```

If you run this code, it works perfectly fine. It draws rectangles of the correct size and color, but when there are two or more of the same color in a row—

```
let myMap = [
  // ...
  ["r", "o", "v", "v"],
];
```

—The first of the duplicates gets rendered correctly, but the second one and all of the ones following it simply get rendered as black. If anyone could help, it would be a lifesaver. Please note that I am relatively new to JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that when you have multiple colors in a row, `indexOf` always finds the first--it's a linear search that walks index by index from the first element of an array to the last until it finds a match. Choosing the wrong index means it'll re-draw over an already existing square rather than putting it in the new location.

The fix is to use actual counter indices in the loop, either with a traditional C-style `for` loop, `forEach`, or with manual index variables:

```js
const colors = {
  r: "red",
  g: "green",
  b: "blue",
  y: "yellow",
  o: "orange",
  bl: "black",
  w: "white",
  t: "transparent",
  i: "indigo",
  v: "violet",
  c: "cyan",
};

const map = [
  ["r", "o", "r", "g"],
  ["b", "i", "o", "v"],
  ["o", "y", "g", "b"],
  ["i", "v", "r", "o"],
];

function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 400);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  rectMode(CENTER);
  drawMap(map, 50, 50, 150, 150);
}

function drawMap(bitmap, x = 0, y = 0, w, h) {
  bitmap.forEach((row, i) => {
    row.forEach((block, j) => {
      push();
      fill(colors[block]);
      noStroke();
      translate(x, y);

      // If a width and height are specified,
      // render it as a rectangle with that size.
      if (w && h) {
        scale(w / width, h / height);
      }

      rect(
        j * (width / bitmap.length),
        i * (height / row.length),
        width / row.length,
        height / bitmap.length
      );
      pop();
    });
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/1.6.0/p5.js"></script>
```